# -M Script start time minus file modification time, in days

Tags: perl, perldoc

I would expect `-M $_` to be negative, but it is zero for:

```
perl -E 'qx(touch $_), sleep(5), say -M for "/tmp/file"'
```

Does [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) mentions such behavior?

Comment: To get a negative value, you should do the `sleep` *first*.

Comment: @MichaelCarman yes, indeed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this explains what you are seeing

```
perl -E 'say "START TIME",$^T; qx(touch $_), sleep(5), say -M for "/tmp/file"; say "STAT ON FILE", (stat(_))[9]'
```

output when I ran it

```
START TIME1434460114
0
STAT ON FILE1434460114
```

1) script starts $^T is set to 1434460114

2) almost immediately the file "/tmp/file" is made with a modify time of 1434460114

3) sleep for 5 seconds

4) -M reports the difference of the modify time on the file and the script start time as zero

try this  instead

```
perl -E 'say "START TIME",$^T;  sleep(5),qx(touch $_), say -M for "/tmp/file"; say "STAT ON FILE", (stat(_))[9]'
```

output on my system

```
START TIME1434460296
-5.78703703703704e-05
STAT ON FILE1434460301
```